# How can I access the ganglia web interface with ssh tunneling to monitor my EMR job?

Tags: hadoop

Ive been using the standard hadoop monitoring tools with:

```
ssh -L 9100:localhost:9100 -L 9101:localhost:9101 -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i key.pem hadoop@ec2-blah-blah-.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

And then just using my browser to navigate to localhost:9100 to monitor the instances. I've been installing ganglia though, and want to know how to access the ganglia web interface via the same method.

I read that the default port for ganglia is 8649, so I tried:

```
ssh -L 8649:localhost:8649 -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i key.pem hadoop@ec2-blah-blah-.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

and going to localhost:8649, but that didn't work.

I can use ganglia using the method described by [amazon's emr documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_Ganglia.html). But this web tunneling method should work too, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the ganglia web interface to access ganglia in any meaningful way through your browser (default port 80). The 8649 port (a default ganglia port) is not used for the web interface but instead for send-receive of your monitoring data.  So you want the web interface and apache and all that.  if you need it encrypted you can use your ssh tunneling on port 80 or whatever your have configured or use ssl